# Deploy Mezzanine CMS on CentOS

Tags: python, django, centos, mezzanine

I have a really big problem ... I'm trying to make a production server (on CentoOS 6) to deploy a mezzanine cms on it . The problem is that I've researched it a lot and cannot find something to work. I'm a little noob at this but I've tried with nginx but cannot find a tutorial that works from one end to another ... same with apache + mog_wsgi . With apache2 I'm blocked at configuring the virtual host ... because what I found is related to pure django and it seems to be differences between django and mezzanine (I know that mezzanine is based on django :) ). Can you guys help me with this one ? I'll really appreciate it :)

Thanks in advance,
Sorin!

Comment: Try what you found for "pure Django". That should also work for deploying Mezzanine (which is basically just a Django App) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorin,

These steps worked for me when launching a new instance of centOS 6.3.  This includes Cartridge and a few other things, but Mezzanine is installed.

```
yum -y install httpd
yum -y install wget
yum -y install vsftpd
yum -y install unzip
yum -y install mercurial
yum -y install java-1.6.0-openjdk
yum -y install mod_ssl
yum -y install mod_python
yum -y install mod_wsgi
yum -y install MySQL-python
yum -y install mailx
yum -y install openssh-clients
yum -y install git
yum -y install python-imaging
yum -y install python-imaging-devel
yum install python-setuptools
yum -y install gcc
sudo easy_install pip
pip install virtualenv
pip install mezzanine
pip install -U cartridge
```

Comment: For future reference, you can chain those commands such as `yum -y install httpd wget unzip mod_ssl` ... and so on.